# C# Inversion of Control - Getting all classes that instantiate base class

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control

There are a few programs I've seen this in, but I'm not sure I know what its called. Essentially, they will take a variety of classes:

Class1

Class2

Class3

Each of these classes has a variable maybe called order or step number:

```
[IClassBaseRunner]
public Class1 : IClassBase
{
    public int step{ get { return 10; } }
...

[IClassBaseRunner]
public Class1 : IClassBase
{
    public int step{ get { return 30; } }
...

[IClassBaseRunner]
public Class1 : IClassBase
{
    public int step{ get { return 20; } }
...
```

All of these classes are part of an Interface like IClassBase. Now they can do something where they don't have to initialize any of the classes, but each of them have to have an attribute above the declaration of the class like [IClassBaseRunner]. With all of this in tact, it will run all of their components without being instantiated independently. They'll add each class to a list essentially and run the steps in order. If you added a step 4, all you have do is add a line above the initialization of the class, kind of like its in the namespace, like the following:

```
[IClassBaseRunner]
public Class4 : IClassBase
```

I'm not sure what its called, but if someone has any information on it or what to search for, that would be great. Its something to do with inversion of control and attributes.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can search "Dependency injection" for a start

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure the exact pattern you're illustrating, but it seems to at least fall into the basic strategy pattern.

Based on your mention of not needing to instantiate classes or add boostraping code when you include new classes... This is something a good dependency injection lib and conventions-based strategy can help with.  Add in some sort of assembly scan, and you should rarely have to deal with configuring components.

Below is an example of how this might be accomplished using Ninject and the Ninject Conventions extension (Nuget package ninject.extensions.conventions).    This example doesn't require any attribute decorators as your question demonstrates, but you could create and use them if you need to.

Also, Structure Map and MEF are other popular dependency injection libraries you might experiment with and see what works best for you.

```
static IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
void Main()
{
    //
    // Automatic binding using 
    // Ninject.Extensions.Conventions
    // Generally, you only want to declare your
    // DI container once in the application lifetime
    // Expecially in web apps, you will also need to 
    // consider the scope of bound classes, such as:
    //   Transient, Thread, Singleton, or Request
    kernel.Bind(x=>x
        .FromThisAssembly()
        .SelectAllClasses()
        .BindAllInterfaces()
    );
    //
    // Now we can resolve the loader and run it
    // Compare this code to how it would look if you
    // manually instantiate all the dependencies and consider:
    // - How much additional code is there?
    // - How easy is it to perform unit tests on the various
    //   components (Mocking is useful here)?
    // - What is the effort if I need to swap out a service
    //   such as IMessageWriter?
    //
    // IMPORTANT: For example only. Do not use kernel.Get()
    // all over your code base.
    // This results in a ServiceLocator anti-pattern! 
    ProcessRunner runner = kernel.Get<ProcessRunner>();
    runner.Execute();
}

public interface IMessageWriter{
    void Write(string message);
}

public class MessageWriter : IMessageWriter
{
    public void Write(string message){
        Console.WriteLine ("MESSAGE: {0}", message);
    }
}

public interface IProcessStep {
    int Step{ get; }
    void Execute();
}

public class ProcessRunner
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IProcessStep> steps;
    public ProcessRunner(IEnumerable<IProcessStep> steps)
    {
        this.steps = steps;     
    }

    public void Execute(){
        steps
            .OrderBy (o => o.Step)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(i=>i.Execute());
    }
}
public class ProcessStep1 : IProcessStep
{
    private readonly IMessageWriter writer;
    public ProcessStep1(IMessageWriter writer)
    {
        this.writer = writer;       
    }
    public int Step { get { return 10; }}
    public void Execute(){
        writer.Write("Hello from step1!");      
    }
}
public class ProcessStep2 : IProcessStep
{
    private readonly IMessageWriter writer;
    public ProcessStep2(IMessageWriter writer)
    {
        this.writer = writer;       
    }
    public int Step { get { return 20; }}
    public void Execute(){
        writer.Write("Hello from step2!");  
    }
}
public class ProcessStep3 : IProcessStep
{
    private readonly IMessageWriter writer;
    public ProcessStep3(IMessageWriter writer)
    {
        this.writer = writer;       
    }
    public int Step { get { return 30; }}
    public void Execute(){
        writer.Write("Hello from step3!");  
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
MESSAGE: Hello from step1!
MESSAGE: Hello from step2!
MESSAGE: Hello from step3!
```